# Magento 2 add data to core_config_data

Tags: magento2, setup

I'm having problems with programmatically configuring Magento 2.1. How can I add data to `core_config_data`?

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    $config = $this->mutableScopeConfig;
    $config->setValue('design/footer/copyright', 'Copyright © 2016 swiatksiazki.pl');

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your setup script:

```
$data = [
            'scope' => 'default',
            'scope_id' => 0,
            'path' => 'design/footer/copyright',
            'value' => 'Copyright © 2016 swiatksiazki.pl',
        ];
  $setup->getConnection()
           ->insertOnDuplicate($setup->getTable('core_config_data'), $data, ['value']);
```

See more: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/InstallData.php`

Answer (score 3):

I thinking of other approach in which you should define your configurations in `etc/adminhtml/system.xml` and their default values in `etc/config.xml`

Why are you trying to insert these configuration from install script? If you want to upgrade some configurations then your approach is ok. But if you want to insert your modules default configuration then I think this way with the xml files is better.

Example of `etc/adminhtml/system.xml` file with two groups:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <!-- Add new Tab -->
        <tab id="vendor" translate="label" sortOrder="300">
            <label>Vendor Extension</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="modulename" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="140" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Modulename Settings</label>
            <tab>vendor</tab>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="api_key" sortOrder="30" type="text" translate="label" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>API Key</label>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="second" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Second Group Title</label>
                <field id="examplefield" sortOrder="40" type="text" translate="label" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Example label</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Then you can set default values with `etc/config.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <modulename>
            <general>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
            </general>
            <second>
                <examplefield>test</examplefield>
            </second>
        </modulename>
    </default>
</config>
```

Then you can see the configurations in `Stores -> Configuration` section and edit you module settings in Vendor name tab.

Comment: Can you share an example code of system.xml - I don't have a clue what it might look like. Also, my goal was to configurate the entire store, and be able to update that configuration easily, without re-installing entire Magneto 2. Can you do that with system.xml?

Comment: Updated my answer with examples of these two xml files.

Comment: That seems useful if you're trying to add your **own custom configuration** info, but I was editing the core Magento 2 configuration...

Comment: It's not a good idea to change/update other modules configuration with setup scripts. I gave you example how to handle configurations in your modules. It's not a good practice to change core magento functionalities/configurations.

Comment: It's not really changing other modules' configuration, more changing magento core configuration, like tax rules, store email, country settings etc. - just the things you can change manually from admin panel, but need it to be set automatically every time we deploy Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Khoa, it works but I also found another way.

```
protected function upgradeVersionOneOneZero()
{
    $this->configResourceModel->saveConfig('general/country/destinations', 'PL', 'default', 0);
}
```

Seems a bit simpler and you can chain all your configuration code.