# How do I add values to core config data when a module is being installed.?

Tags: magento2

I have a set of config that I need to add to core config data table when my module is being enabled. Data also needs to be deleted when the module  is being disabled

Comment: Can you please explain more about your concern? if you want save some configuration in core_config_data table then you should have some fields in admin panel.for that we write code in our system.xml of module under *etc/adminhtml*.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link for add values to core config data when a module is being installed.

[Magento 2 add data to core_config_data](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143577/magento-2-add-data-to-core-config-data)